# R Shiny change reactiveVal twice

Tags: r, shiny

So I have a R Shiny app where the initial value of secs() is NULL. When I click the button it changes to 10 seconds. After the 10 seconds, secs() needs to change to 30 seconds. However when I click the button secs() changes immediately to 30 seconds, without waiting for 10 seconds, why?

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("ReactiveVal Example"),
  mainPanel(
    actionButton("btn", "Click Me!"),
    textOutput('output')
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  secs <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  ready <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  
  # Observing the button click event
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    
    secs(10000)
    ready(TRUE)
    
    
  })

  # Observe the change in secs after 10 seconds
  observe({
    req(ready())
      invalidateLater(secs())
      secs(30000)  # Set to 30000 milliseconds (30 seconds)
  })
  
  output$output <- renderText({
    paste("Current value of secs:", secs())
  })
  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are less convoluted approaches, but adding another `reactiveVal` to keep track of observer invalidations (well, we only need to know if it's the first cycle or not ..), isolating reactives and keeping `invalidateLater()` in `on.exit()` seems to achieve what you are after.

```r
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("ReactiveVal Example"),
  mainPanel(
    actionButton("btn", "Click Me!"),
    textOutput('output')
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  secs <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  ready <- reactiveVal(FALSE)
  observe_counter <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  # for logging
  start_time <- reactiveVal(Sys.time())
  from_start <- \(start_time) difftime(Sys.time(), start_time, units = "secs") |> as.numeric() |> round()
  
  # Observing the button click event
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    secs(10000)
    ready(TRUE)
  })
  
  # Observe the change in secs after 10 seconds
  observe({
    message(sprintf("+%.4ds observe({req(ready() ...})", from_start(start_time())))
    req(ready())
    isolate({
      if(observe_counter() > 0){
        secs(30000)
      }
      observe_counter(observe_counter() + 1)
      on.exit(invalidateLater(secs()))
    })
  })
  
  output$output <- renderText({
    message(sprintf("+%.4ds output$output <- renderText(), secs() = %.d", from_start(start_time()), secs()))
    paste("Current value of secs:", secs())
  })
  
}
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Produces following log (time in seconds since app start):

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7895
+0000s observe({req(ready() ...})

+0002s output$output <- renderText(), secs() = 10000
+0002s observe({req(ready() ...})
+0012s observe({req(ready() ...})
+0012s output$output <- renderText(), secs() = 30000
+0042s observe({req(ready() ...})
+0072s observe({req(ready() ...})
```

As for why `secs()` changed twice and without a delay -- `invalidateLater(secs())` does not delay execution, it says that after x milliseconds, the observer is invalidated, though it doesn't mean invalidation can't happen before that if wired reactives are changing; the next statement, `secs(30000)`, is evaluated during that same (1st) cycle, which in turn triggers that observer again.

Comment: Thx! i had to re-read it a couple of times but def of help!

Comment: is there also a way to invalidateLater at the onset/start of the observer? so instead of on.exit...on.start?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow. I mean, you clearly can, as this is what you did in the code example of your question. There's also `reactiveTimer()` -  https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-reactivity.html?#timed-invalidation - perhaps it's a better fit for your use case. And maybe consider looking more into https://mastering-shiny.org/reactivity-intro.html , or just https://mastering-shiny.org/reactive-graph.html , it covers reactive execution.